# hapi js api design joi validate error

Tags: mongodb, hapi.js

While designing hapi js API with mongoose, facing issue with designing the joi validation for nested schemas. I am a newbie please help with the error

---

### models/ vahana.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var vahSchema = new Schema({

vehRegNumber: { type: String, required: false, unique: true},

techSpecMeta: {

    make: String,
    model: String,
    height: Number,

    vehBodyType: String,
    seatingCapacity: Number,
    doorCountr: Number,


    stdCityMilege: Number,
    stdHighwayMilege: Number,
},


servSpecMeta: {
    assignedDriver: {
        name: String,
        contact: Number,
        license: {
            regNo: { type: String, required: false, unique: true},
            dateOfIssue: Date,
            validDate: Date,
        }
    },

    buy: {
        purchaseDate: Date,
        purchaseDealer: String,
        purchasePrice: Number,
    },

    servicing: {
        servicingDate: Date,
        serviceStation: String,
        serviceCost: Number,
    }

},

dynmSpecMeta: {
    date: Date,
    busRoute: {
        path: String,
        distance: Number,
        avgTime: Number,

    },
    distCovered: Number,
    fuelConsumption: Number,
}
})

var Vahana = mongoose.model('Vahana', vahSchema);
module.exports = Vahana;
```

---

### server.js

```
// ================ Base Setup ========================

var Hapi = require('hapi');
var server = new Hapi.Server();
var Joi = require('joi');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/vahanaDB');

var vahModel  = require('./models/vahana');

server.connection({port: 7002});

server.register({
register: require('hapi-swagger'),
options: {
    apiVersion: "0.0.1"
}
}, function (err) {
if (err) {
    server.log(['error'], 'hapi-swagger load error: ' + err)
} else {
    server.log(['start'], 'hapi-swagger interface loaded')
}
});



// =============== Routes for our API =======================


// POST route

server.route({
method: 'POST',
path: '/api/vehicle',
config: {
    tags: ['api'],
    description: 'Save vehicle data to mongodb',
    notes: 'Save user vehicle to mongodb',
    validate: {
        payload: {

            vehRegNumber: Joi.string().required(),
            techSpecMeta.make: Joi.string().required()

        }
    }
},
handler: function (request, reply) {

    var vehicle = new vahModel(request.payload);

    vehicle.save(function (error) {
        if (error) {
            reply({
                statusCode: 503,
                message: error
            });
        } else {
            reply({
                statusCode: 201,
                message: 'User Saved Successfully'
            });
        }
    });
}
});

// =============== Start our Server =======================
server.start(function () {
console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
console.log('I am running on localhost:7002');
});
```

I am getting following error after running
nodemon server.js

techSpecMeta.make: Joi.string().required()
                            ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a key like "techSpecMeta.make" it needs to be in quotes.

```
 payload: {
    vehRegNumber: Joi.string().required(),
    'techSpecMeta.make': Joi.string().required()
  }
```